# Is there any option in Camel Spring Boot application to shutdown the JVM process after processing all the message?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

My requirement is to terminate the Java process after processing all the messages from the source location. I am using following technology-
Spring-Boot - version 2.2.4.RELEASE
Camel - version 3.0.1
Open-JDK- version 11.0.3.7-1

I have used camel.springboot.duration-max-idle-seconds=10 option. After waiting 10 sec, it invokes shutdown hook and close spring and camel context. After that, java process not get terminated. I am not understand which actually blocking to terminate the java process?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug about not terminating completely. This is fixed in the upcoming Camel 3.2.0 release.

As a workaround you can do your own kind of "detect idle after" and then do a terminate - System.exit to force JVM to terminate etc.